# ¿Cómo ocultar un ImageButton en un GridView dependiendo de un valor en la misma fila en C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo un GridView con estas dos columnas en donde la primera muestra si tiene o no complemento y en la segunda se muestra un ImageButton como una imagen de descarga de PDF, así:

[image: GridView Original]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando la primera columna (ID COMPLEMENTOPAGO) tenga el valor de "Sin complemento" no se muestre el ImageButton (imagen PDF, segunda columna), esto para todas las filas?

La primera columna (complemento) la tengo como:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO" HeaderText="ID COMPLEMENTOPAGO"></asp:BoundField>
```

La segunda columna (PDF) la tengo como:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="60px">
<HeaderTemplate>
    PDF FACTURA
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdPDf2" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/pdficon.png" runat="server" CommandName="SelectPDF2" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("NRO_FOLIO") %>' 
    AlternateText="Descargar PDF" />
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle Width="40px" />
    <ItemStyle Width="40px"
 HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Lo intenté con RowDataBound, de la siguiente forma:

```
  protected void miGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          DataRowView myDataRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
          if (myDataRowView["ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO"].ToString() == "Sin complemento")
          {
              ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("cmdPDf2");
              imgBtn.Visible = false;
          }
      }
  }
```

Pero no obtuve lo deseado.

El resultado deseado es este:

[image: Resultado deseado]

Nota: la forma en que lleno el GridView es la siguiente:

1.- Lleno un DataTable desde un SP (BD)

2.- despues el GridView lo lleno con lo obtenido en el DataTable, así:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = miSP...............
 miGrid.DataSource = dt;
 miGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
 miGrid.DataBind();
```

Soy nuevo en C# asp.net, por favor si alguien puede ayudarme..

Comment: No es necesario agregar `[solucionado]` al título, basta con que aceptes una de las respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente haces que la propiedad `Visible` del `ImageButton` dependa de lo que esté escrito en `ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO`, de esta manera

```
<asp:ImageButton 
  ID="cmdPDf2" 
  ImageUrl="~/imagenes/pdficon.png" 
  runat="server" 
  CommandName="SelectPDF2"
  AlternateText="Descargar PDF" 
  Visible='<%# Eval("ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO").ToString() == "Con complemento" %>'  />
```

*La última línea es lo nuevo y debes notar que se empieza con comillas simple y se usa `ToString()`*

Entonces, cuando `ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO` tiene el texto `Con complemento`: `Visble=True`, en cualquier otro caso `Visible=False`

Comment: Justamente encontré y publiqué la solución hace unos minutos, es exactamente lo que dices, ¡¡gracias!!

Comment: @JesusZavala Si!! me di cuenta que respondimos casi al mismo tiempo. Ojo que no es necesario usar el operador `?` para devolver `true/false`, ya que los operadores `==` y `!=` ya devuelven `true/false`

Answer (score 0):

Después de días de buscar, la solución que encontré es muy sencilla:

Directamente en el diseño (.aspx):

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdPDf2" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/pdficon.png" runat="server" 
Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO" ).ToString() != "Sin complemento" ? true : false %>' CommandName="SelectPDF2" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("NRO_FOLIO") %>' 
AlternateText="Descargar PDF" />
```

La respuesta está en el **Visible**, utilizando el operador ternario (como el if), obtengo si en la columna ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO tiene "Sin complemento".

Como está dentro del propio ImageButton entonces se mostrará o no dependiendo del valor en ID_COMPLEMENTOPAGO.